# C++ Button that changes Tabpages

Tags: c++, winforms

I've been making a C++ Windows Forms application as a login system. I need to know the code of a button click event that changes from tabpage1 to tabpage2.

I've searched the whole internet and all I found was this code:
`tabControl1.Selectedtab = mytab` which doesn't work for me showing an error at `tabControl1`

Take a look at my code:

```
code:private: System::Void label5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Error Code:

```
system::windows::forms::tabcontrol^project1::myform::tabcontrol1 expression must have a class type
```

Comment: Standard c++ doesn't have any notion about the functionality (_C++ forms application_ in particular) you're talking aboiut. Narrow your question to be more specific about compiler, OS and GUI framework used please.

Comment: _@Arianit_ You are required to post a [mcve] reproducing your actual problem here. _"Doesn't work"_ isn't an appropriate problem description. You'll need to be more specific about error messages and such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ here is the code for it. It is a situation when a button can change tabpages from one to other

Comment: Most likely since is c++ tabconrol1 is refrence you have to use             
    tabcontrol1->Selectedtab, just like we use pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out
the code must be:
tabControl1->SelectedTab = tabPage3;